# How to insert function inside class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to ask why I get an error when I want to include a function in a class?

Is there any other way to include the function inside the class?

```
class Barang {
        constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk) {
            this.Nama = Nama;
            this.Harga = Harga;
            this.Merk = Merk;
    
        }
    }
    
    class Kategori extends Barang {
        constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk, Kategori, Jenis) {
        super(Nama, Harga, Merk);
        this.Kategori = Kategori;
        this.Jenis = Jenis;
        }
    
        function Ongkir(berat) {
            var berat = berat;
            var biaya = function (){
                return berat * 8000
            }
        
            this.totalBiaya = function () {
                return biaya()
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `function` keyword

```js
class Barang {
        constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk) {
            this.Nama = Nama;
            this.Harga = Harga;
            this.Merk = Merk;
    
        }
    }
    
    class Kategori extends Barang {
        constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk, Kategori, Jenis) {
        super(Nama, Harga, Merk);
        this.Kategori = Kategori;
        this.Jenis = Jenis;
        }
    
        Ongkir(berat) {
            var berat = berat;
            var biaya = function (){
                return berat * 8000
            }
        
            this.totalBiaya = function () {
                return biaya()
            }
        }
    
    } 

var test = new Kategori();

console.log(test.Ongkir());
```

Answer (score 1):

To define a function inside the class, just set the name. And pay attention that you don't need to use the keyword `function || const` before the name.

P.S. You forgot to close a curly bracket.

```js
class Barang {
  constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk) {
    this.Nama = Nama;
    this.Harga = Harga;
    this.Merk = Merk;
  };
};

class Kategori extends Barang {
  constructor(Nama, Harga, Merk, Kategori, Jenis) {
    super(Nama, Harga, Merk);
    this.Kategori = Kategori;
    this.Jenis = Jenis;
  };

  Ongkir(berat) {
    var berat = berat;
    var biaya = function() {
      return berat * 8000
    };

    this.totalBiaya = function() {
      return biaya()
    };
  };
};
```